# I need a batch file to find files with specific extension and add in them one line of text

Tags: file, text, find, addition

I'm completly new and dont know a thing about creating batch files. I used to study informatics but now I'm car mechanic :)
I've got few computers in few places containing VMware machines that need to be edited.
Exactly VMX files need to add one line of text (to autodetect one usb device).
All machines are on C: drive.
Can anyone help me out with this? I just dont want to edit every file manually as some computers would have to be done with teamviewer as they are not around here.
In summary:
Need batch file to find every VMX file on C drive and add in every file one line of text: usb.autoconnect.device0 = "0x20A2:0x0001"
Thank you for your time reading this.
Regards!

I'm not really into doin this things so I have not tried anything.